# Add CSS pseudo element to SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to Add CSS pseudo element to an SVG? I wish to add text to the SVG element with the `content: ();` property.

Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/MrThunder/pen/mKvNRb)

```css
.grade1 {
  stroke: #07FF00;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: #BBFFA6;
}

.grade1::after {
  content: "Grade 1";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43.4" height="43.4">
       <circle class="grade1" cx="21.7" cy="21.7" r="19.2"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Comment: why not a simple text element ?

Comment: @Alexander not a duplicate, it's not about the SVG as a content .. but to add content to the SVG

Comment: @Alexander, Turnip saved you :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I'm sorry :)

Comment: @Temani I wanted to add text and styles with css which would give me way more control

Comment: @Turnip this in not a duplicate, I am adding content with a pseudo element not styling it. Thanks

Comment: it's a duplicate because the answer is simply : "you cannot use pseudo element" and this is what the duplicate explain